# windows mobile 6.5 - Motorola MC55 - strange directory names in device explorer view

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync

On Windows XP in device explorer view while I explore the content of my connected via Active Sync Motorola MC55 device I can see strange content. Look at the attached file.
[image]

What may be wrong?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks a whole lot like the FAT is corrupted on the file store.  A bad flash driver can cause this as well, but that would typically show up immediately and on every device.  If it's a single device, or happened after time then it's likely a flash sector corruption.  Reformatting the flash will likely correct it (though how you do that on your harward I don't know).